# Passing a variable from a controller into a route param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, routeparams

```
....           

.state('books', {
            url: '/book/chapter/:chap',
            templateUrl: "views/chapter.html",
            params: { chap: .........}
        })
```

Hi!
I have a variable in a specific controller and I want to pass it's value into a param for routing. Eventually I want to change the value of that variable so that I can create new urls using this same route.

I'm using ui-router, as you may have noticed.

I'm also curious on how would you solve the following problem:
basically I want to open a specific chapter of a book, let's say chapter 5. Then I want to display at the left of the page a link for each remaining chapter, that's why I want to change the value of the variable. How would you solve this using ng-repeat?
I'm thinking of using getArticle (as shown below) to get a chapter number and then ng-repeat the remaining chapters with ng-repeat? Ideas?

```
angular
    .module('BookLibrary')
    .controller("ChapterController", ["$scope","stateParams", "ChapterControllerService", function($scope, $stateParams, ChapterControllerService){

        $scope.chapterList = ChapterControllerService.chapters;
        $scope.getArticle = chapterList[0].chapter;

    }]);
```

chapterList looks like this:

```
chapterList = [
        { 
            chapter: "1",
            content: "Chapter 1 goes here"
        },
        {
            chapter: "2",
            content: "Chapter 2 goes here"
        },
        {
            chapter: "3",
            content: "Chapter 3 goes here"
        }
    ];
```

Comment: How could we know? You didn't tell us what $scope.chapterList is, nor what $scope.getArticle is. Without knowing your model, we can't tell you how to use it.

Comment: @JBNizet my bad, there it is :)

Comment: So, you need `<a ng-repeat="c in remainingChapters" ui-sref="books({chap: c.chapter})">{{ c.content }}</a>`. And you need to set $scope.remainingChapters to the sub-array starting at the next chapter. What have you tried? What's the concrete problem? And why do you use a string instead of a number for the chapter number?

Comment: Yeah, I'll turn it into a number and then change to a string for the route param.
what about the configuration of the routes? How do I establish the param?

Comment: Hve you read my comment? It contains a complete example. Al you need is the logic to extract the remaining chapters from the chapters. That is pure JS logic.

Comment: Yes I read it, but shouldn't there be something in "params" here: ?
.state('books', {
            url: '/book/chapter/:chap',
            templateUrl: "views/chapter.html",
            params: { chap: .........}
        })

Comment: No. You don't need params. Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple questions here so to start with your state parameters. In the state params you can declare default values for params in a state like so.

```
.state('books', {
        url: '/book/chapter/:chap',
        templateUrl: "views/chapter.html",
        params: { chap: null}
    })
```

This would default the value to null. Perhaps you always want to default to chapter 1? If that was the case you can use `params: {chap: '1'}` (since you are using strings).
 To pass a value to the state there are multiple ways to do it. Assuming you are using `ui-sref` you can hand parameter values right in the link.

```
ui-sref="books({ chap: 3 })"
```

However you want to have a list of links from an object using ng-repeat. So you could do something like this

```
<ul>     
   <li ng-repeat="chapter in chapterList">
      <a ui-sref="books({chap: chapter.chapter})">{{chapter.chapter}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

You've included $stateParams in your controller already so you just need to grab the parameter from it like so

```
angular
.module('BookLibrary')
.controller("ChapterController", ["$scope","$stateParams", 
"ChapterControllerService", function($scope, $stateParams, 
ChapterControllerService){

    $scope.currentChapter = $stateParams.chap;

    $scope.chapterList = ChapterControllerService.chapters;
    $scope.getArticle = chapterList[0].chapter;

}]);
```